# Struggling to figure out database structure for multiple relationships

Tags: database, data-structures

I am creating a laravel application to track campaigns in a game. The database structure situation I am struggling to figure out involves the following tables:

- Campaign

  - Id
  - Name
- Character

  - Id
  - Name
- Item

  - Id
  - Name

The campaign table is empty.
The Character table is populated with character data from the game.
The Item table is populated with item data from the game.

Both the Character and Item tables hold data from the game itself and should not be populated with user data.

A user can create a new campaign which will create an entry in the Campaign table.
The user can then select characters to use in the campaign. I can create this relationship with a campaign_character link table.

The issue arises when it comes to items. Items can be purchased, at which point they need to be added to the current campaign. I could use a campaign_items link table for this, but items can also be optionally equipped by characters in the campaign. I'm not sure how to handle this relationship.

I can't create a character_item link table because the relationship is not between a character and an item directly, it's between a character in a campaign and an item in a campaign.

My current thinking is to make a campaign_character link table, a campaign_item link table, and a campaign_character_campaign_item link table, but this scenario appears many times (not just with characters and items, for example characters can then add attachments to items) and I feel like this will just lead to a ton of tables and complex relationships.

Is there a better way to handle this or is this the right way?

Thank you for any guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion

Apart from 3 main tables create your link tables as

```
campaign_character
campaign_item
```

In your `campaign_item` create a nullable column called `equipped_by` and store `character_id`.

If this column has a character_id that means this item_id is equipped by that character, if it has null item is not attached to a particular character.

---

For attachments create a link table `item_attachment` to hold only the link between items and attachments.

Since the connection between `character` and `item` is already established in `campaign_item` table, the link between `attachment` and `character` can be derived from `campaign_item` and `item_attachment` tables.

Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it normal to have extra columns in the link table? For some reason I thought it should only be the ids of the tables that it will link.

Comment: Based on your needs you can add an additional column, it will save you from another table and more complicated design. You can "bend the rules" according to your use case, it boils down to "architecture design decision"